# Newsletter Subscription Form display text

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, newsletter, onsubmit

I need help with my Newsletter form

1. How to ensure form cannot be submited empty
2. Avoid adding same email from users in data
3. When click on Subscribe button, show a simple text message as Thank You for subscription instead of directing to action.php.

form.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Subscribe to our Mailing list</h3>
<form action="add.php" method="post" id="embed-form" >
Your Name..
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
Your Email..
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submi" value="Subscribe">
<span id="success-message" class="email-success"</span>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Connect.php

```
<?php
 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","subscriber");

 //Check Connection
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
     echo "Failed to connect to MySqli";
     mysqli_connect_errno();
 }
?>
```

add.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['email'])){
    $n=$_POST['name'];
    $e=$_POST['email'];
    $s=$_POST['submit'];

    $query=("INSERT INTO newsub (name, email) VALUES ('$n','$e')");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    echo "Thank you for your subscription";
}   

?>
```

Comment: 1. is straightforward: add [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#required) attribute to input tags. 2. and 3. require some design thinking. When and how do you want to alert the user that the email is already subscribed or that subscribing was successful? Probably requires ajax call to `add.php` on submit event.

Comment: Thank You @DinoCoderSaurus : Using required att fixed first request. With regards to 2 and 3: Same email need not be re entered by user and valid email should be used, Finaly user should see Thank you message right below button and not redirect to another page. I am trying to use ajax but seems to be difficult for me. Can any one suggest me with a code?